# Is it possible to create custom AMP tags?

Tags: amp-html

As the title goes: is it actually possible to build my own tags? As in:

```
<amp-mytag />
```

And have it to interact with the AMP environment? Does AMP actually expose some API to register custom components?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to try and contribute on github and get your PR's approved by the Google AMP team.